# Wordpress redirect all 404 pages to the Homepage

Tags: plugins, htaccess, code

I want to redirect all 404 error pages on my WordPress site to the homepage, or to a specific page.
Any advice?

Comment: have u downvoted my question? do you know it's not your good answer.

Comment: i get it fixed by https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-404-redirect-to-homepage/ this plugin.

Comment: i get it fixed by wordpress.org/plugins/all-404-redirect-to-homepage this plugin. but i still want to use code instead of plugin.

Comment: Don't redirect 404 page to homepage. It's bad for SEO and it might remove information that could help you fix your links. Save yourself the trouble and just use the 404 page to find your errors and fix them.

Comment: It's probably a better idea to design your 404 page to include relevant information from your homepage and/or include a link to your homepage.  It can be confusing to users, and hurt your SEO / search engine ranking to blanketly redirect without sending a 404 code for non-existant pages.  404 error codes serve a useful purpose.  If you do insist on doing so, you should, at a minimum, track these redirects, so that you can fix errors. This plugin that can do both [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/). If you change the URL of a page, use it to redirect to your updated page.

Comment: @MaxYudin Aadii is new, in future be polite and link to the rules,  if that's not enough call in a moderator or flag things. There's no need for all caps and exclamation marks

Comment: @Tom I'll strive to be nice, but I become mad when new people does not read the rules and can't represent the problem before posting. Mostly I'm mad when I'm drunk but soon I'll sign off.

Comment: @MaxYudin that's their problem not yours, you don't have to involve yourself on every post, but browsing the site while drunk is not a good idea, perhaps you should step away from the computer after a drink

Comment: @Tom I want to help somebody even when I'm drunk, but 80% of questions are out of scope of this site or are methodless formulated and it enrage me. People searching for the good answer can't find an answer because of such kind of people asking.

Comment: That's what downvoting and close voting are for, anyway lets leave the comments for the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ***Note: I have read somewhere that redirecting all 404 to Homepage is***
>   ***not a good approach for SEO purposes***

---

Simplest way to redirect all 404 to homepage in wordpress.

```
if( !function_exists('redirect_404_to_homepage') ){

    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_404_to_homepage' );

    function redirect_404_to_homepage(){
       if(is_404()):
            wp_safe_redirect( home_url('/') );
            exit;
        endif;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a better idea to design your 404 page to include relevant information from your homepage and/or include a link to your homepage.

Simply redirecting all 404's to the home page can be confusing to users, and hurt your SEO / search engine ranking.  It is suggested that you provide feedback to your users why a page they expected to see was not loaded. 404 error codes can serve a useful purpose.

If you do insist on doing blanket redirections, you should, at a minimum, track these redirects, so that you can fix errors.

This plugin that can do both **[Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)**, and more.

A great feature of this plugin, is that if you change the URL of a page within your site, you can specify a "permanent" redirect to the new proper home of your page.

If you monitor the 404's on your website, you can also identify mistakes, such as a typo in your html, that may be producing an unintended 404.  You can then both fix the typo, and add a specific redirect to forward any requests for that mistyped link, to redirect to the correct url. Then visitors, whether using *either* link will arrive on the intended page.

You can also use the log to identify spelling mistakes that originate from typos on other sites linking to yours.  Again, you can add a specific redirect that intercepts the typo and forwards them to the proper page.  You could even try emailing them to inform them of their typo. They may or may not fix it, but either way, you are able to automatically direct users to the correct website.

Note, when you view the list of 404's logged by this (or any) plugin, you will see a ton of bad requests that are "bots" trying to find vulnerabilities in your website.  These requests can either be ignored, redirected to a specific page (such as localhost, or your home page), or you can set a rule to kick them off your system after a certain number of bad requests.
For the most part, you will want to focus on 404's that are obviously the result of typos, or urls that once existed, but have either changed, or been removed altogether.

In the case of pages that have been deleted, then permanently redirecting those links to the home page may be the proper answer.